# Does an index improve performance when using modulo?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Imagine a `MySQL` table with one field `id` containing 1 billion rows from number 1 to a billion.

When I do a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 2000 AND id < 5000;
```

It is obvious that an index on `id` will improve the performance of that query.

However does such an index also help with modulo as in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id % 4) = 0;
```

Does using an index help when using modulo?

Comment: @Isaiah : do you mean it would help in that last example? I'm not sure myself, but I have trouble figuring out how something like a BTREE index would go about and do something with a modulo: only the actual values are saved, right, so there is no 'knowledge' about that modulo: it'll prolly need a table scan. Not completely sure though.

Comment: I think it would still do a table scan for all the records..

Answer (score 5):

No.

Functions on columns used in an index (almost) always preclude the use of the index.  Even if this weren't true, the optimizer might decide not to use an index anyway.  Fetching just one out of four records may not be selective enough for the index to be worthwhile.

Comment: so you are saying, that when you use modulo on a column with an index and on a column without an index, the performance is the same? I don´t get the answer. First, you say no, and then you say the exact opposite in the first sentence. So either I or you misunderstood the question :D pls help me out here.

Comment: @Luke . . . It says the same thing in two different ways.  The use of a function probably prevents the index from being used.  Selecting 25% of the records is probably too many to efficiently use an index.  If English is not your first language, look up "preclude" -- it means that the index is not being used.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle DB for example you can define so called *function based indices* for your purpose where you define that modulo function in the index. But I'm pretty sure function based indices do not exist with MySQL.

What you *could do* as a workaround is **adding a additional column** where you store the result of your modulo function. You have to modify your insert scripts  fill it for future inserts and update the existing data sets. Then you can add an index to that column and use it in your where clause.